# I want to use Wide Char in my program, but most XML Parser don't support Wide Char

Tags: c++, xml, widechar

I'm developing a program on Windows and I'm using Wide character. And I'm not using ATL/MFC, just pure standard C++. Now I need a XML Parser. I tried tinyXml but it doesn't support wide char. 
I know MSXml supports wide char but I don't want to use it because it uses COM and is a little complicated. And I worry about what if user's OS does not have MSXML service installed.
Any idea what should I do? A new XML Parser?

Comment: Libraries generally don't use wide strings. Better to have UTF-8 strings and convert them to UTF-16 when needed. `std::wstring_convert` can do that.

Comment: thanks, i tried your suggestion